# Neo4j Cypher query DB hits optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have the following Cypher query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (p:Profile)  MATCH (v:Vacancy:Decision {id: 17210})
WHERE NOT exists((v)<-[:POSSIBLE_PROFILE]-(p))
RETURN p, v;
```

and only 5000 Profiles in my test DB.

The plan:

[image]

I'm concerned about the number of DB hits highlighted in the green rectangle. Could you please show me how to optimize this query?

Answer (score 2):

Your query creates a cartesian product between all :Profile nodes and the :Vacency:Decision node, then expands from each one of them checking that they're not connected.

It would likely be more efficient to match to the possible profiles from v, then match to all :Profile nodes that are NOT those. Something like this:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (v:Vacancy:Decision {id: 17210})<-[:POSSIBLE_PROFILE]-(possible)
WITH v, collect(possible) as toExclude
MATCH (p:Profile)
WHERE NOT p IN toExclude
RETURN p, v;
```